# Which repo for tor relay on Ubuntu Artful?

Tags: relays, ubuntu

Tried to update a tor relay on a machine running Ubuntu Artful, but the repos at https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org artful/main are gone missing. Any ideas which repos I should use instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should instead **upgrade the machine** to *Bionic Beaver* (18.04 LTS) because *Artful Aardvark* (17.10) is no more supported and thus must be considered as outdated and insecure!

---

if you are unable to upgrade you can likely use the packages from Debian *Stretch* or if not working, try them from *Xenial Xerus* (16.04 LTS) or *Bionic Beaver* (18.04 LTS). BUT it is possible that you'll end sooner or later in [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

but this is just advised for testing and/or learning purpose and i would never use the machine in any production/real environment again before setting up from scratch.